# Named object resource include not found - Omnifaces + JSF 2.2.12

Tags: jsf-2.2, omnifaces

I have an issue with my JSF page since I've installed Mojorra version 2.2.12 (from 2.2.8): it throws an exception when the page is loaded. The exception is: Named object: org.omnifaces.component.output.ResourceInclude not found.

I have the exact same issue with the Mojorra version 2.2.11. I don't have any problem with the version 2.2.8, 2.2.9, and 2.2.10.

Environment: Tomcat 8 + omnifaces 1.11 + jsf 2.2.12 + richfaces 4.5.4.final.

My JSF page includes a JSP fragment through the o:resourceInclude tag (it's not a design choice but rather a technical constraint I have to bear with).

Did I miss something in the configuration of omnifaces so the resourceInclude faces component can be found?

**Edit:**

The following problems arise when I switch to JSF 2.2.12:

1. The named object resourceInclude cannot be found
2. The omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter converter cannot be found
3. When a binding attribute refers to a java bean with a view scope, the said java bean cannot been found
4. I have removed omnifaces from the WEB-INF/lib directory, but I still have the issue #3

Comment: Can't reproduce on a blank project with only OmniFaces and Mojarra, and everything else set to bare defaults.

Comment: Thanks for your time spent on reproducing the issue on a blank project. I've set everything to bare defaults but still have the issue. I've edited the original question since I made some progress and found many other problems.

Comment: How are you managing/deploying the webapp and Tomcat? Are you using Spring Boot? BootsFaces has a very similar problem with Spring Boot when using Mojarra 2.2.11 or newer (but not with 2.2.10 or older). See also http://www.beyondjava.net/blog/updating-to-mojarra-2-2-11-may-break-your-spring-boot-application/

Comment: Hum... this is a very good remark. We are starting Tomcat from within our own software, and our Web Apps are pre-installed in a webapps directory that is referred to in Tomcat's configuration file. Our WEB-INF/lib directory contains many jars, and some of these jars contains code with lambda expressions. We're not using Spring Boot. The symptoms I have look very similar to those of BootsFaces, i.e. the scanning of jar files seems to not working properly.

Comment: Additional information: we are booting Tomcat from within our software via a call to: org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(args);