# Undefined component type net.bootsfaces.layout.***

Tags: jsf, bootsfaces

I am trying to setup bootsfaces in my JSF application, I am seeing below error, can someone please help?

```
org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl Undefined component type net.bootsfaces.layout.Row

at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:1437)
at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:1405)
at org.jboss.weld.integration.webtier.jsf.ForwardingApplication.createComponent(ForwardingApplication.java:122)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.createComponent(ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.java:576)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegate.java:284)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:50)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:46)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:86)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:178)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.TemplateContextImpl$TemplateManagerImpl.apply(TemplateContextImpl.java:193)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.TemplateContextImpl.includeDefinition(TemplateContextImpl.java:136)
```

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot or something like that to bootstrap your web application? If so, then this is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32799225/javax-faces-facesexception-expression-error-named-object-net-bootsfaces-layou

Comment: I suspect that's the same question as https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/198.

Comment: The issue on the BootsFaces bug tracker made me suspect your classpath contains path MyFaces and Mojarra. If that's true, please fix this. Both libraries are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score -1):

If it helps any one, I have unzipped all the files into class path now it is working fine.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend anyone to do this on any web library. In order to naildown your real problem and fix it the right way, post a MCVE, or even better, a reproducer WAR at BootsFaces issue tracker.

Comment: It's interesting to learn that unzipping BootsFaces.jar has some effect, but I agree with Bauke: We could help you a lot better if you provided us a reproducer. You know, we love to help you, but we need some clue to do so. Reluctantly, I closed the issue on the BootsFaces bug tracker (and I'd be more than happy to re-open it if you gave us something to work on).