# Named Object: net.bootsfaces.component.container.Container not found

Tags: jsf, bootsfaces

when I try to run  BootsFaces-OSP-1.4.1 in weblogic 12.3.2 I am getting the following error.

```
<Mar 5, 2019 3:40:53,887 PM GMT> <javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application> <jsf.cannot_instantiate_component_error> <JSF1068: ******Cannot instantiate component with component-type net.bootsfaces.component.container.Container>******
Mar 05, 2019 3:40:53 PM org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandler logException
<Mar 5, 2019 3:40:53,890 PM GMT> <org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandler> <Expression Error: Named Object: net.bootsfaces.component.container.Container not found.
SEVERE: Expression Error: Named Object: net.bootsfaces.component.container.Container not found.
javax.faces.FacesException: Expression Error: Named Object: net.bootsfaces.component.container.Container not found.
javax.faces.FacesException: Expression Error: Named Object: net.bootsfaces.component.container.Container not found.
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponentApplyAnnotations(ApplicationImpl.java:1912)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:1166)
at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.createComponent(ApplicationWrapper.java:637)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.createComponent(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:602)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:175)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

I am using the following frameworks
```

JSF Version : 2.2.17 
    Primefaces : 6.1

NetBeans :8.2

```
None of the components are working in weblogic 12.3.2.  The same code works perfectly fine with glassfish 4.1 server. 
Thanks and Regards
JEBA J****
```

Comment: Where did you place the bootsfaces jar file? Does this thread help: [javax.faces.FacesException: Expression Error: Named Object: net.bootsfaces.layout.Well not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32799225/javax-faces-facesexception-expression-error-named-object-net-bootsfaces-layou) ?

Comment: I have placed it in the WEB-INF/lib directory of web folder. Its a ear application with one ejb jar file and one war file.

Comment: Also Its getting Deployed.

Comment: Thanks Kukeltje . It was on the wrong path in the build. Now its working fine. Thanks